# No me actualiza un check a true

Tags: javascript, array, state

estoy haciendo un **filtro para filtrar por años una tabla**,
el problema, creo, es que **no me actualiza el valor a TRUE**, pongo el codigo a ver si me podeis echar una mano.

```
//actualiar el check del filtro:

  const [checked, setChecked] = useState([]);
  const handleCheck = (event) => {
    var updatedList = [...checked];
    if (event.target.checked) {
      updatedList = [...checked, event.target.value];
    } else {
      updatedList.splice(checked.indexOf(event.target.value), 1);
    }
    setChecked(updatedList);
  };

// console.log( typeof checked)
  //Aplicar cambios en la tabla
  const handleApply = () => {
    setDropdownOpen(false);
    //console.log("APPLY");

    const newState = stateCheckYear.map(obj => {
      // ️ if id equals 2, update country property
      if (checked.some(v => (v === obj.year))) {
        console.log("es igual")
        console.log(typeof obj.year);
        return { ...obj, check: true }; // no me cambia el check a true 
      
      }
      console.log("NO checked")
      console.log(obj.year);
      return { ...obj, check: false };

    });
    applyYearFilter(newState);
  };

  console.log(stateCheckYear)
```

el console log de es igual y el tipo de dato de obj.year lo hace, por lo que esta entrando ahi, pero el statecheckedyear (es un dato que traigo del padre) me sigue apareciendo ese registro como false.

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

a ver si esto te ayuda ... si el valor de stateCheckYear viene del padre, estas intentando cambiar el valor de un objeto del padre, desde el hijo.
En el hijo es una prop, y cambiando el objeto no cambia automáticamente en el padre, para hacerlo puedes pasar la prop y además el método de useState que le cambia el valor, cuando cambia el objeto, llamas al método que le cambia el valor (este método es del padre).
Pero te recomendaría mandar eventos hacia arriba, las props viajan hacia abajo, los eventos viajan hacia arriba. El hijo manda un evento de que el año XXX debe cambiar a true y el cambio del objeto ocurre en el padre cuando recibe ese evento.

Aqui puedes ver un ejemplo/explicacion
[ejemplo](https://john-florez.gitbook.io/reactjs-book/lifting-datos-de-hijos-a-padres)

Saludos y suerte !!

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).